# How to set up a shell script after I login

Tags: bash, cron, debian

I'm trying to set up a Script which opens the shell and asks a few questions (it's done for new workers).

I've tried to set it up via crontab, via init.d, and many other ways which I can't remember.

That's what I have on the crontab file

```
@reboot bash /home/user/newUser
```

Eitherway, I've tried to add `#!/bin/bash -l` to the script

I reboot and there's no response: no script executing

Comment: Your new user environment might be created from `/etc/skel`. In this case you could start with `/etc/skel/.bashrc`. You need to invent a mechanism to prevent repeated execution though.

Comment: Sounds something like the RedHat family's "firstboot" package.  I'm not sure how customizable that is, or how amenable it would be to adaptation for Debian, but it might at least be worth taking a look at how it does things (which involves hooking the systemd service control framework).

Comment: welcome to [so] a forum for programming questions. your problem seems to be unrelated to actual programming, and instead is targeted at system integration. you might have more luck asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), esp. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384304/ as suggested by @MarPan